# What does passing true or false to a callback in a yeoman generator do?

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am trying to understand the `this.async()` pattern within yeoman generators and I came across something confusing within the generator-generator code:

https://github.com/yeoman/generator-generator/blob/master/app/index.js#L108-L111

Up until now I've been using this:

```
var done = this.async();
// do some stuff...
done();
```

But what does passing `true` and `false` to done() do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, `done` and `this.async()` are for an [`inquirer`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/inquirer) `prompt`, which Yeoman's [`this.prompt()`](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/blob/v0.17.7/lib/base.js#L193-L196) [wraps](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/blob/v0.17.7/lib/env/adapter.js#L26-L37).

Within the `prompt`'s `when` handler, the argument determines whether or not to display the prompt to the user:

> - **when**: (Function) Receive the current user answers hash and should return `true` or `false` depending on whether or not this question should be asked.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't realize `this.async()` was contextual. Thanks for the info!